# How to add "cold-reset" MOSFET to a I²C chip? Should it be a P-MOS or N-MOS?

Tags: i2c, reset, reliability

## Background

I have a device which sports a couple of "IMU" chips - ICM-20602 and LIS3MDL - which both do not have reset functionality on a pin. They do have the ability to be rebooted by a software command, via a write to a I²C register.

I have encountered cases (in rare occasions, and on an old PCB revision, and especially with LIS3MDL), in which one or both chips gets stuck in some very low-level buggy state, something akin to a latchup of the analogue part: the chip consumes a ton of current, e.g. 100mA vs the usual <1mA, and while its I²C interface works perfectly, the sensor itself does not: it outputs a triangular signal. Sending the software reset commands indeed reset the I²C state, but do not help with the magnetic sensor - it continues to be stuck.

I guess the proper way to really address this issue is to run the PCB with EMC experts, devise improvements, talk with ST, etc., etc., all of these are planned, especially the EMC issues is going to be tackled by making the PCB a 4-layer one.

However, I want to be sure that I have a software way to correct the low-level latchup-like behaviour, because the chip does not seem to be damaged, and is always corrected by a cold reboot. The device runs on battery, and if it depletes and the BMS cuts the 3V3 power, the chips are then fine and working perfectly when they are powered up again.

## Resetting I²C chips

Since the I²C bus is pulled up to 3.3V, I have two options to add a power-cut transistor to the IMU chips - either a PMOS at the Vdd side, or a NMOS at the Vss side, like this

### PMOS option

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAdPxV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Note: the I²C pull-ups are global to the whole bus)

### NMOS option

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJHaWQ.png)</sup>

- I think the IMU chips need to be held <1s in cold-reset to fix the latchup, probably much less;
- In both cases, the I²C bus will be unusable while the IMU chips are cold-reset, but this is OK;
- I plan to use a single transistor to reset both chips;
- In the PMOS case, I guess the other I²C devices on the bus might not like that the bus becomes floating, but I could just pull both of these down via the main MCU, or even orchestrate it to look like clock stretching. In any case, the bus recovery will likely be not an issue, even if it takes may milliseconds of setup.

## Question

Which implementation would you recommend? Are there any pitfalls that I'm not considering?

Comment: But if you have a way to reset a chip by turning off power, how do you detect that the chip is in buggy state in software so you know when to reset it? It might be better to develop a solution to the problem so it does not happen, instead of developing a workaround for a problem when it happens.

Comment: Detecting the buggy state is not hard, and I already have it. Of course, solving the root cause is the best approach, but that would take time, and I'm trying to get the new PCB revision out, which might as well fix it, and the reset circuitry is just in case the problem persists, so I still have some improvement over the existing PCB revision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the PMOS option so there is no risk of a low SCL or SDA pulling the input below Vss.

But better than that might be an LDO regulator with enable pin and "active discharge" pull-down that will discharge any bypass capacitance that might be on the Vdd line smartly.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when a chip has connections to other chips via IO pins, disconnecting the GND pin of a chip to remove power is not a great idea. Also, since I2C bus pins (and many other buses too) floats high when idle, it may be a bad idea to remove supply unless the pull-up resistors are on the disconnected supply, so they can't pull high when chip is unpowered.

As it happens, Analog Devices has an appnote AN-686 which is about implementing a reset to I2C devices, and faling that the problem is not on the I2C bus, there is a suggestion how to disconnect the supply (not ground).

Depending on how much the chip consumes power (both during normal use and in the fault condition), the idea of using an analog multiplexer may suit your purposes.